# Equal area map projections: Lambert azimuthal or Albers conic?

Tags: coordinate-system, cartography

When making small-scale regional maps on the order of 500-5000 km in extent where an **equal-area** projection is desirable, which would you prefer, the Lambert azimuthal or Albers conic? I realize this could be a matter of the cartographer's personal preference and graphical constraints (e.g. aspect ratio of the final map), but is there a general rule of thumb about when to choose one projection over another?

Answer (score 4):

It depends also on the location you want to map which you did not specify.

From ArcGIS Help, on `Albers Equal Area Conic`:

> **Limitations**
>
> Best results for regions predominantly east–west in orientation and located in >the middle latitudes. Total range in latitude from north to south should not >exceed 30–35°. No limitations on the east–west range.
>
> **Uses and applications**
>
> Used for small regions or countries but not for continents.
>
> Used for the conterminous United States, normally using 29°30' and
> 45°30' as the two standard parallels. For this projection, the maximum
> scale distortion for the 48 states is 1.25 percent.
>
> One method to calculate the standard parallels is by determining the
> range in latitude in degrees north to south and dividing this range by
> six. The "one-sixth rule" places the first standard parallel at
> one-sixth the range above the southern boundary and the second
> standard parallel minus one-sixth the range below the northern limit.
> There are other possible approaches.

ArcGIS Help for `Lamert Azimuthal`:

> **Limitations**
>
> The data must be less than a hemisphere in extent. The software cannot
> process any area more than 90° from the central point.
>
> **Uses and applications**
>
> - Population density (area).
> - Political boundaries (area).
> - Oceanic mapping for energy, minerals, geology, and tectonics (direction).
> - This projection can handle large areas; thus it is used for displaying entire continents and polar regions.
> - Equatorial aspect: Africa, Southeast Asia, Australia, the Caribbean, and Central    America.
> - Oblique aspect: North America, Europe, and Asia.

Comment: There are a few few helpful rules in the above, but is still not particularly informative. ArcGIS says to not use Albers for a continent but one often sees North America plotted in an Albers projection, even if it squashes the high latitudes...

Comment: I see, I am not familiar enough with North America being from western Europe

Comment: I think the answer from @MarcM is very informative but perhaps the use of one projection over another is subjective and hence a matter of opinion.